# hiding password in textbox except last letter

Tags: c#

I would like to make a login screen with a masked (`*`) textbox, but I want to mask every character with an asterisk `*` except for the last letter typed (which should be visible in clear text).

For example when the password is `123` and I type `1` the contents of the textbox will be shown as `1` (as this was the last letter typed in). But when I enter `2` after `1` the contents of the textbox will be shown as `*2` and when I type `3` the contents of the textbox will be shown as `**3`.

But i cannot solve the algorithm:

```
private void txtPw_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string inputString = txtPw.Text;
        int index = inputString.Length;
       // char lastChar = inputString[inputString.Length-1];         
        txtPw.Text = "";           
        tempPassword += lastChar;
        for(int i=0;i<(index-1);i++)
        {
            txtPw.Text += "*";
        }
        txtPw.Text += lastChar;     
    }
```

This is what I have got so far. `tempPassword` is for checking id pw inf.
As an additional information: Visual Studio tells me in the commented line: `array is out of range` (if that helps).

thanks for every help

Comment: First of all, `lastChar` is commented out, so you con't be able to access it in `tempPassword+= lastChar

Comment: I would suggest getting the length of the field, if it's bigger than one, the you can append as many `*` as you want but the last one

Comment: This will not work because TextChanged is not suitable. It will be called no matter what changes you make at any position, inserting or cutting. So you can't keep track of the real password. Look into KeyDown or KeyPressed with suitable checks and maybe prevent any keys but allowed ones, ie no editing but backspace and no positioning..

Comment: @Taw has an excellent point, in fact you should get a stack overflow.

Comment: @Mayhem no no you got it wrong i made it commented for intentionally to show which line give me the error

Comment: No, he has it right, the code is commented out, purpose aside.

Comment: Anyhow, you want..the keypress event(I'm coding VB6 today, so i may have my event names mixed)

Comment: You may have some issues with the code when you have deleted all the string characters, because you are asking for Length -1, if length is 0 you will look for -1

Comment: Don't you want to actually store the password somewhere? What if they press backspace? You have no way of knowing what the actual last character is in order to show it.

Comment: The use of a password box suggests a user interface is in play, but I don't see what framework you are using for UI. Certainly any answer along these lines would require this knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a perfect answer this will work to mask the characters as you asked if you are only allowing people to change the last character being input in the string (I.e. backspace at the end of the password or a new letter at the end).  For usability sake it also used a global variable called "currentPassword" to allow for you to check if it is correct later.

This code can be optimised further and modified to reduce the number of lines using sub-functions but I tried to just keep it in one to allow for easier copy and pasting for you.

Kind regards, 
Shadow

```
string currentPassword = "";

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var currentInputBox = sender as TextBox; // More general way to handle inputs for a text event if using multiple text boxes all with the same function
            var inputString = currentInputBox.Text;

            if (inputString.Length > currentPassword.Length) // Adds the new letter to the global variable currentPassword and then masks the original text box used
            {
                var newChar = inputString.Substring(inputString.Length - 1);
                currentPassword += newChar;
                var newBoxText = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < currentPassword.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    newBoxText += "*";
                }
                newBoxText += newChar;
                currentInputBox.Text = newBoxText;
            }
            else if ((inputString.Length < currentPassword.Length) && (inputString.Length > 0)) // Removes characters from the currentPassword field til it matches the length of the textbox field and then exposes a single character at the end
            {
                currentPassword = currentPassword.Remove(inputString.Length, currentPassword.Length - inputString.Length);
                var newBoxText = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < currentPassword.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    newBoxText += "*";
                }
                newBoxText += currentPassword.Substring(currentPassword.Length - 1);
                currentInputBox.Text = newBoxText;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, [this article](https://css-tricks.com/better-password-inputs-iphone-style/) discusses how to create an iPhone-style password input box on the web using jQuery.  However, based on the code, I'm assuming you are trying to do similar in either WinForms or WPF.

So, the general solution requires the following:

1. Code that intercepts the [`Control.KeyPress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.keypress?view=netframework-4.7.2) event
2. A field on your class that contains the text that was typed (which you intercepted with the event above - note that you'll also need to catch backspaces).
3. Logic that inserts a character, but replaces it with a bullet character [ • ] after a brief (perhaps 1 second) delay, into the text box.

So, you end up with two strings - the string of bullets which is printed in the text box, and the actual string. If you're using WPF, you might even be able to code up a fancy value converter to handle this automagically.

As a consideration, you would also need to think about what might happen if a user selects a substring and decides to replace text (do you show that particular character as they type)? Writing a full control for you seems to be a bit much, but hopefully this gives some thoughts as to how to proceed.